# Hold Form.ShowDialog-State when showing new form

Tags: c#

I am working on a project and so far it works fine.
I have 3 forms and there will be more then, but now to the problem:

When the program starts **Form1** will be shown. On a button I call this to open a new form:

```
Form2 frm = new Form2();
frm.ShowDialog();
```

Well, this works fine. Form2 will be shown in front of **Form1** and if I close it **Form1** is again the main form.

In **Form2**, I want to do the same, now, but **Form2** should be closed and **Form3** should be in the front. Well, this is not very difficult, but when I call it like that...

```
Form3 frm = new Form3();
frm.ShowDialog();
this.Close();
```

... **Form2** will not close, because of ShowDialog. What can I do? I want that **Form3** is in the front, **Form2** is closed and **Form1** is still there, but I cannot click on it, as Form3 should be called with *ShowDialog*.

At the moment **Form3** is shown over **Form2**, but I want that it is shown over **Form1**.
What can I do to solve this?

Of course the forms have other names, it is just to make it easier to understand.

Here you can see two pictures for understanding it better:

This is how it looks:
http://www.directupload.net/file/d/3508/xmy99iwq_png.htm

**Form2** is visible, but I want it to be closed.

Like here:

http://www.directupload.net/file/d/3508/qjvy42wq_png.htm

But I want that **Form3** is in the front and you cannot click on Form1, like I called **Form3** with *ShowDialog* in **Form1**.

Comment: cant you just switch the order to close form2 before calling `frm.ShowDialog();`

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @Jonesy Logically not, because when I close Form2 before, I cannot show the new form and I also do not want to hide it.

Comment: do you always want form3 to show when form2 is complete? Or is there a scenario where form2 should close, but form3 should not be shown

Comment: It should always show it, as a solid order.

Answer (score 1):

Don't have `Form1` call `Form2.ShowDialog`.  Have it call some other methods instead.  Add a new method to `Form2` that does what `Form2` *should* do when shown, such as this:

```
public class Form2 : Form
{
    public void Display()
    {
        ShowDialog();
        Form3 dialog = new Form3();
        //TODO pass in parameters
        dialog.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

Another option would be to have some entirely separate class handle this, possibly `Form1`, or possibly some other type that is essentially a public "wrapper" to `Form2` and `Form3`, so that users of those forms (i.e. `Form1`) only ever use this wrapper class that would look something like this:

```
public class Foo //TODO give better name
{
    public void ShowPopups()
    {
        Form2 firstDialog = new Form2();
        firstDialog.ShowDialog();
        Form3 secondDialog = new Form3();
        //TODO pass in parameters
        secondDialog.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```